# MySQL IN Clause with Array issue

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My IN clause works in the first query but not in the 2nd. The larger query works just fine without the IN clause so there are no issues there. Looked through docs but couldn't see where I am going wrong.

Works:

```
'SELECT email, first_name, last_name 
    FROM users 
WHERE user_id 
    IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval',$userData)) . ')'
```

Does not work:

```
'SELECT
    u.user_id, u.email, u.first_name, u.last_name, a.job_id, a.user_id, ap.job_id, ap.app_id, ap.location, p.user_id, p.filename, p.selected, g.street, g.city, g.state
FROM users u
    JOIN applications ap ON ap.user_id = u.user_id
    JOIN applicants a ON a.user_id = a.user_id AND a.app_id = ap.app_id AND ap.job_id = a.job_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_photos p ON u.user_id = p.user_id AND p.selected = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_general g ON u.user_id = g.user_id
WHERE
    u.user_id IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval',$userData)) . ')'
```

Error:

**Couldn't execute query. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 9**

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not work'? Which errors do you get? Besides, shouldn't `JOIN applicants a ON a.user_id = a.user_id AND a.app_id = ap.app_id AND ap.job_id = a.job_id` be `JOIN applicants a ON a.user_id = ap.user_id AND a.app_id = ap.app_id AND ap.job_id = a.job_id`

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: Sorry meant to post! **Couldn't execute query. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 9**

Comment: You are probably ending up with an empty `IN ()` clause. You must inspect and then post the actual SQL statement you are executing, _after_ any PHP code has been interpreted inside it, but in all likelihood, `$userData` does not contain what you expect it to, resulting in empty output from `implode()` and breaking the SQL.

Comment: Prior to execution I'm printing contents of $userData just to be sure it isn't empty. The first and smaller query returns proper results. Thanks -- I'll print the query to see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, sorry. The issue lied with the JOINS not the IN clause. None of the IDs being requested have rows for applications. Changed JOIN to LEFT OUTER JOIN did the trick.

```
'SELECT
    u.user_id, u.email, u.first_name, u.last_name, 
    a.job_id, a.user_id, ap.job_id, ap.app_id, ap.location, 
    p.user_id, p.filename, p.selected, g.street, g.city, g.state

FROM users u

    LEFT OUTER JOIN applications ap ON ap.user_id = u.user_id
    JOIN applicants a ON a.user_id = a.user_id AND a.app_id = ap.app_id AND ap.job_id = a.job_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_photos p ON u.user_id = p.user_id AND p.selected = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_general g ON u.user_id = g.user_id
WHERE
    u.user_id IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval',$userData)) . ')'
```

Comment: Good find. If you have the ability to do so, please mark your question as an answer to give closure to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `implode` function is eventually returning an empty string and therefore you are seeing this issue.

Take this example of having empty values with the `in` keyword and notice similar error.

```
mysql> create table test(field1 int);
mysql> insert into test values (1);    
mysql> select * from test where field1 in ();

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

Comment: So my confusing grows because the first query works just fine. Why would the second return an empty string?

Comment: It's hard to say without debugging but here's what you could try. Execute both queries in a single PHP file. Right before you execute the queries, do `var_dump(implode(',', array_map('intval',$userData)))` and notice for any oddities.

Comment: $userData appears to be fine. I'll need to rebuild this and see where the issue lies. Thanks for looking